# get maximum and minimum price of products in a collection based on final price in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to find the minimum and maxinum price of products so that I can use it to set the range of my price filter. I used the getMaxPriceInt() and getMinPriceInt() methods in Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php. However the value returned to is based on the 'min_price' field.

How do I find out the minimum and maximum price of products in a collection based on the final_price? That is if there are 4 products in the collection(i'm enlisting only needed fields)

```
prodid   min_price  final_price
3         5200       5900
44        8347       8900
54        4536       5765
12        7436       7500
```

the getmaxpriceint() and getminpriceint() return me 8347 and 4536 respectively.

My result should be 8900 and 5765 respectively. Is it possible to make some changes to the existing methods in Price.php to achieve it or is there any other alternative?

I dont want to loop around the products and get the final price in an array and sort as I feel that,it would not be the optimised approach. I also dont want to use setOrder() and then get the min and max price as it would affect the sort order of the collection.

In general as well, Can you please suugest what's the best way in magento to get the maximum and minimum value of a field directly from the product collection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this extension. I think I might be helpful.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-price-ranges.html

Comment: Thanks, its a cool extension. I had solved the problem by modifying the queries in the methods mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

$maxPrice = $this->getMaxPriceInt();

$minPrice = $this->getMinPriceInt();